# How can I add this line on Pages?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, pages

How can I add this line on Pages? Is there a shortcut? I can only repeat press <kbd>-</kbd>.

If this is not possible on Pages, similar layout will also be OK.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have Pages automatically add a line across the whole page, the formatting options (dash size etc.) are rather limited though:

[image]

You can also use the fill option when setting tabs:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add a rule to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text** and have it replace `---` by any number of dashes you’d want.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> gives you an em dash (–) if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in Pages directly, but you can add a text shortcut for the line.
This can be done in Settings.app via Keyboard -> Text.